# how to get a greater value with numbers containing 2 decimal points

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way we can find which is a greater version i.e to find if 1.0.1 is greater than 1.0.13 in php or mysql...

Any help appretiated,
Thank You

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - especially how to provide a good example of what you have tried so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`version_compare`](http://php.net/version_compare) is a builtin PHP function used for exactly that (comparing version numbers); that'll do what you're asking.

```
version_compare('1.0.1', '1.0.13'); // -1
version_compare('1.0.1', '1.0.1'); // 0
version_compare('1.0.13', '1.0.1'); // 1
```

---

#### From the docs:

> version_compare() returns -1 if the first version is lower than the
>   second, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if the second is lower.

http://php.net/version_compare

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack - although, neatly, this hack also throws up one of the flaws of this approach...

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(GREATEST(INET_ATON('1.0.1'),INET_ATON('1.0.13'))) greatest;
+----------+
| greatest |
+----------+
| 1.0.0.13 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a hack:

```
select
    concat(substring_index('1.0.1', '.', 1), substring_index('1.0.1', '.', -2)) + 0 as ver1,
    concat(substring_index('1.0.13', '.', 1), substring_index('1.0.13', '.', -2)) + 0 as ver1,
    concat(substring_index('1.0.1', '.', 1), substring_index('1.0.1', '.', -2)) + 0
    >=
    concat(substring_index('1.0.13', '.', 1), substring_index('1.0.13', '.', -2)) + 0 as result

+------+-------+--------+
| ver1 | ver1  | result |
+------+-------+--------+  
| 10.1 | 10.13 | 0      | 
+------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select greatest('1.0.1', '1.0.13');
```

Hope this helps.